# MVC3 JsonSerializer finds mysterious circular references?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, activerecord, serialization, universe

This has been asked before, but not about this specific problem. Almost all the responses I have read deal with the entity framework being serialized. I am trying to serialize an object following the ActiveRecord pattern that contains some information from a MultiValue database (UniVerse) and although I thought the structure of my data holding classes was very simple, JsonSerializer insists on finding circular references and I cannot for the life of me figure out where the circular reference is being found.

My object has this sort of structure to it:

```
/// <summary>
/// Textbook Active Record
/// </summary>
public class TextbookActiveRecord
{
    public DBValue<string> ISBN { get; private set; }
    public DBValue<string> Synonym { get; private set; }
    public DBValue<DateTime> LastUpdate { get; private set; }
    public DBValue<string> Author { get; private set; }
    public DBValue<string> Title { get; private set; }
    //....up to 70 more properties for some of my tables....

    protected TextbookActiveRecord() { }

    public static TextbookActiveRecord GetByISBN(string isbn)
    {
        //....Creates a new object and fills in the values above...
    }
}
```

The DBValue class is just a wrapper class which lets me treat every value as if it were a generic if I need to by downcasting to DBValue (no <T>) while also allowing all types to be nullable. When I try to serialize an instance of this object created from TextbookActiveRecord.GetByISBN() I get the circular reference error. None of my DBValue objects use classes other than string, float, int, or DateTime as their template.

I have tried implementing the ISerializable interface and using the GetObjectData method to populate a SerializationInfo object, but through the use of exceptions I have seen that it looks like that method isn't even getting called (putting a throw right at the beginning of the method does nothing at all).

Does anyone know what in the world is wrong with this? Could it be the static methods or maybe the protected constructor?

Even knowing how I can find the particular property that is giving it the circular reference would be really really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Serializing a class with methods has given me headaches as well.  Using linq in the methods was my problem.

I got around this by removing the methods and adding them as extension methods so that the actual class serialized only consists of properties.